# Ruby - Hide "^C" on Interrupt

Tags: ruby, interrupt

In Ruby I have the following:

```
# Trap Interrupts
trap("INT") do
    puts "Shutting down..."
    exit
end
```

When I interrupt the program, the following is printed (Mac OSX Lion):

> ^CShutting down...

Is there any way to hide `^C` from within Ruby?

Comment: Begin the exit message with a 'C' (something like `Closing link...`) and then omitting the 'C' :)  (Still would have the `^` though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether control characters are echoed is a property of the tty you're using. `stty -echoctl` is the Unix way to disable echoing of control characters. You can run this command from within your Ruby script and achieve the same effect if you're using a Unix-ish system.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that in my Python programs on Linux and Mac OS X terminals I can hide the ^C by starting the message with a carriage return (\r). It feels like a hack but it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use backspace characters to erase the `^C`:

```
trap("INT") do
    puts "\b"*2 + "Shutting down..."
    exit
end
```